# how to make a CNN so that my program can tell the difference between a photo and a drawing?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-2010, conv-neural-network

i have a folder full of over 12,000 images. i'd like to make a program to redirect drawings to the drawing folder and photos to the photo folder. I'm in my 1st year of engineering school and I don't know how to go about it. Can you please help me?

for the moment i've coded a program that detects if there's text on the images (my drawings often have text) but there are some that don't so they're not taken into account. after some research i've seen that it's necessary to make a CNN and now i'm lost.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.